# D3 js - is it possible to draw straight lines between tree nodes?

Tags: d3.js

I have created a horizontal tree diagram as shown in below image. I want straight lines between nodes. The curved lines between nodes are default in d3 js. I saw some answers on google for this but did not found any satisfactory result. So is it possible to draw straight lines between nodes in d3 js? If yes then how can I do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAm8D.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   

    <style>
        .node circle {
            fill: #ff9900;
            stroke: #ff9900;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }
        
        .node text {
            font: 16px sans-serif;
        }
        
        .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #ccc;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script language="javascript">
        var treeData = [{
            "name": "1",
            "parent": "null",
            "children": [{
                "name": "2",
                "parent": "Persons",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "3",
                    "parent": "Country of residence"
                }, {
                    "name": "4",
                    "parent": "Country of residence"
                }, {
                    "name": "5",
                    "parent": "Country of residence"
                }, {
                    "name": "6",
                    "parent": "Country of residence"
                }]
            }]
        }];

        // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
        var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 120,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 120
            },
            width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var i = 0;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([height, width]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) {
                return [d.y, d.x];
            });

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return d.lx;
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return d.ly;
            });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



        root = treeData[0];

        update(root);

        function update(source) {

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 180;
            });

            // Declare the nodesâ€¦
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function(d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });

            // Enter the nodes.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 40)
                .style("fill", "#ff9900");



            // append icon inside circle
            nodeEnter.append("image")
                .attr("xlink:href", "http://localhost/d3/user2.jpg")
                .attr("x", "-18px")
                .attr("y", "-18px")
                .attr("width", "35px")
                .attr("height", "35px");


            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -40 : -50;
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? 55 : 55;
                })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start";
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Declare the linksâ€¦
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function(d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                });

            // Enter the links.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", diagonal);


        }
    </script>
</body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why do you still use D3v3? Where you use `diagonal` create a function that based on the arguments you get an SVG path with `M` and `L` parts.

Comment: why do you have **2** body close tags?

Comment: Thanks rioV8. I am new to D3 JS. In latest version I was getting few errors so instead of solving those I preferred to keep the old version but I will definitely upgrade my app to latest version. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your line :

```
        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return d.y; // because tree is horizontal
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return d.x; // because tree is horizontal
            });
```

Change your links function to this because d3.svg.line() takes array of points as argument

Hope this helps

```
        // Enter the links.
        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                return line([d.source, d.target]);
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   

    <style>
        .node circle {
            fill: #ff9900;
            stroke: #ff9900;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }
        
        .node text {
            font: 16px sans-serif;
        }
        
        .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #ccc;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script language="javascript">
        var treeData = [{
            "name": "1",
            "parent": "null",
            "children": [{
                "name": "2",
                "parent": "Persons",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "3",
                    "parent": "Country of residence"
                }, {
                    "name": "4",
                    "parent": "Country of residence"
                }, {
                    "name": "5",
                    "parent": "Country of residence"
                }, {
                    "name": "6",
                    "parent": "Country of residence"
                }]
            }]
        }];

        // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
        var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 120,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 120
            },
            width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var i = 0;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([height, width]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) {
                return [d.y, d.x];
            });

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return d.y;
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return d.x;
            });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



        root = treeData[0];

        update(root);

        function update(source) {

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 180;
            });

            // Declare the nodesâ€¦
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function(d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });

            // Enter the nodes.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 40)
                .style("fill", "#ff9900");



            // append icon inside circle
            nodeEnter.append("image")
                .attr("xlink:href", "http://localhost/d3/user2.jpg")
                .attr("x", "-18px")
                .attr("y", "-18px")
                .attr("width", "35px")
                .attr("height", "35px");


            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -40 : -50;
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? 55 : 55;
                })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start";
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Declare the linksâ€¦
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function(d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                });

            // Enter the links.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function(d) { return line([d.source, d.target])});


        }
    </script>
</body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems like old thread still let me ask, can lines be perpendicular instead of connecting straight to child nodes? Like going up or down and then towards right.

Comment: @Gangesh Can show can example ? Perpendicular to what ?

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4435809/a096c5e073eff8d7c3cdf9892d82e154 Here is an example of lines.