# How to make curved lines to straight lines for Hierarchy Chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

[image: Source Image]

I found one sample example in d3.js with employees hierarchy.I am facing issue while changing the curve lines to straight line like below image.

```
var attrs = {
    EXPAND_SYMBOL: '\uf067',    
    COLLAPSE_SYMBOL: '\uf068',
    selector: params.selector,
    root: params.data,
    width: params.chartWidth,
    height: params.chartHeight,
    index: 0,
    nodePadding: 9,
    collapseCircleRadius: 7,
    nodeHeight: 50,
    nodeWidth: 210,
    duration: 750,
    rootNodeTopMargin: 20,
    minMaxZoomProportions: [0.05, 3],
    linkLineSize: 180,
    collapsibleFontSize: '10px',
    userIcon: '\uf007',
    nodeStroke: "#ccc",
    nodeStrokeWidth: '1px'
  }

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {      
      return [d.x + attrs.nodeWidth / 2, d.y + attrs.nodeHeight / 2];
    });
```

I have tried with the above two codes.I am unable to get the curves like below Image.Could you help me on this issue.

[image: Target Image]
<sub>(source: [noaa.gov](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/about/img/ESRL-NOV-2017-ORGCHARG.png))</sub>

Below link is Chart refrence link.

[Employees Hierarchy Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/willzjc/a11626a31c65ba5d319fcf8b8870f281)

Comment: See the same but with straight lines here:https://github.com/bumbeishvili/d3-organization-chart

Comment: @DiegoBaranowski It doesn't support orientation like left to right or right to left. Still an open issue.

Comment: I believe this might help you: [D3 js - is it possible to draw straight lines between tree nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551369/d3-js-is-it-possible-to-draw-straight-lines-between-tree-nodes)

Comment: The above example draws straight lines, but I believe @user1495394 wants curve steps like the shown image. By the way, are you using d3 v3?

Answer (score 3):

This is a little hackish, but still works. Replace the definition of `diagonal` with the following.

```js
var line = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {
      return [d.x + attrs.nodeWidth / 2, d.y + attrs.nodeHeight / 2];
    });
var diagonal = d => line(d).replace('C', 'L');
```

It works by converting SVG path definitions for cubic Bezier curves ('C' stands for Cubic) to those for lines ('L' for Line). For example, `M105,40C105,130 -270,130 -270,220` to `M105,40L105,130 -270,130 -270,220`.

Here is the fixed version of your example. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KgomDr/2Lo5j8yc/)

Comment: How to disable click and double click event for zoom behaviours.On click on mouse wheel, how to add zoom behavior for chart. Zoom behavior only on mouse wheel only.

Comment: Hello @hurried-helpful, I'm using this same example(d3 v3), I want to know if we can display the chart vertically, as this chart expands its a child as horizontal align https://prnt.sc/G8D_oUtrbIdd

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.node {
   cursor:default;
}
.node text {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}

.node rect {

}

/* Lines */
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #424242;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#body {
  cursor: move;
  height:700px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var orgChart = (function() {
   var _margin = {
       top:    20,
       right:  20,
       bottom: 20,
       left:   20
   },
   _root           = {},
   _nodes          = [],
   _counter        = 0,
   _svgroot        = null,
   _svg            = null,
   _tree           = null, 
   _diagonal       = null,
   _lineFunction   = null,
   _loadFunction   = null,
   /* Configuration */
   _duration       = 750,        /* Duration of the animations */
   _rectW          = 150,        /* Width of the rectangle */
   _rectH          = 50,         /* Height of the rectangle */
   _rectSpacing    = 20          /* Spacing between the rectangles */
   _fixedDepth     = 80,         /* Height of the line for child nodes */       
   _mode           = "line",     /* Choose the values "line" or "diagonal" */
   _callerNode     = null,
   _callerMode     = 0,

   defLinearGradient = function(id, x1, y1, x2, y2, stopsdata) {
      var gradient = _svgroot.append("svg:defs")
                     .append("svg:linearGradient")
                       .attr("id", id)
                       .attr("x1", x1)
                       .attr("y1", y1)
                       .attr("x2", x2)
                       .attr("y2", y2)
                       .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

      $.each(stopsdata, function(index, value) {
         gradient.append("svg:stop")
                 .attr("offset", value.offset)
                 .attr("stop-color", value.color)
                 .attr("stop-opacity", value.opacity);  
      });
   },

   defBoxShadow = function(id) {
      var filter = _svgroot.append("svg:defs")
                      .append("svg:filter")
                      .attr("id", id).attr("height", "150%").attr("width", "150%");

      filter.append("svg:feOffset")
            .attr("dx", "2").attr("dy", "2").attr("result", "offOut");  // how much to offset
      filter.append("svg:feGaussianBlur")
            .attr("in", "offOut").attr("result", "blurOut").attr("stdDeviation", "2");     // stdDeviation is how much to blur
      filter.append("svg:feBlend")
            .attr("in", "SourceGraphic").attr("in2", "blurOut").attr("mode", "normal");
   },

   collapse = function(d) {
       if (d.children) {
           d._children = d.children;
           d._children.forEach(collapse);
           d.children = null;
       }
   },

   update = function(source) {
      // Compute the new tree layout.
      _nodes = _tree.nodes(_root).reverse();
      var links = _tree.links(_nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      _nodes.forEach(function (d) {
         d.y = d.depth * _fixedDepth;
      });

      // Update the nodes
      var node = _svg.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(_nodes, function (d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++_counter);
      });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
          return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
      })
      .on("click", nodeclick);

      nodeEnter.append("rect")
               .attr("width", _rectW)
               .attr("height", _rectH)
               .attr("fill", "#898989")
               .attr("filter", "url(#boxShadow)");

      nodeEnter.append("rect")
               .attr("width", _rectW)
               .attr("height", _rectH)
               .attr("id", function(d) {
                   return d.id;
               })
               .attr("fill", function (d) { return (d.children || d._children || d.hasChild) ? "url(#gradientchilds)" : "url(#gradientnochilds)"; })
               .style("cursor", function (d) { return (d.children || d._children || d.hasChild) ? "pointer" : "default"; })
               .attr("class", "box");

      nodeEnter.append("text")
               .attr("x", _rectW / 2)
               .attr("y", _rectH / 2)
               .attr("dy", ".35em")
               .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
               .style("cursor", function (d) { return (d.children || d._children || d.hasChild) ? "pointer" : "default"; })
               .text(function (d) {
                         return d.desc;
               });

      // Transition nodes to their new position.
      var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                           .duration(_duration)
                           .attr("transform", function (d) {
                                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                           });

      nodeUpdate.select("rect.box")
                .attr("fill", function (d) {
                    return (d.children || d._children || d.hasChild) ? "url(#gradientchilds)" : "url(#gradientnochilds)";
                });              

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                         .duration(_duration)
                         .attr("transform", function (d) {
                             return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
                         })
                         .remove();

      // Update the links
      var link = _svg.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function (d) {
                          return d.target.id;
                    });


      if (_mode === "line") {
         // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
         link.enter().append("path" , "g")
             .attr("class", "link")
             .attr("d", function(d) {
                           var u_line = (function (d) {
                              var u_linedata = [{"x": d.source.x0 + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": d.source.y0 + _rectH + 2 },
                                                {"x": d.source.x0 + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": d.source.y0 + _rectH + 2 },
                                                {"x": d.source.x0 + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": d.source.y0 + _rectH + 2 },
                                                {"x": d.source.x0 + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": d.source.y0 + _rectH + 2 }];

                              return u_linedata;
                           })(d);

                           return _lineFunction(u_line);
                        });

         // Transition links to their new position. 
         link.transition()
            .duration(_duration)
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                        var u_line = (function (d) {
                           var u_linedata = [{"x": d.source.x + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": d.source.y + _rectH },
                                             {"x": d.source.x + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": d.target.y - _margin.top / 2 },
                                             {"x": d.target.x + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": d.target.y - _margin.top / 2 },
                                             {"x": d.target.x + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": d.target.y }];                                                  

                           return u_linedata;
                        })(d);

                        return _lineFunction(u_line);
                     });

         // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
         link.exit().transition()
             .duration(_duration)
             .attr("d", function(d) {
                             /* This is needed to draw the lines right back to the caller */
                             var u_line = (function (d) {
                                var u_linedata = [{"x": _callerNode.x + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": _callerNode.y + _rectH + 2 },
                                                  {"x": _callerNode.x + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": _callerNode.y + _rectH + 2 },
                                                  {"x": _callerNode.x + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": _callerNode.y + _rectH + 2 },
                                                  {"x": _callerNode.x + parseInt(_rectW / 2), "y": _callerNode.y + _rectH + 2 }];

                                return u_linedata;
                             })(d);

                             return _lineFunction(u_line);
                        }).each("end", function() { _callerNode = null; /* After transition clear the caller node variable */ });
      } else if (_mode === "diagonal") {
         // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
         link.enter().insert("path" , "g")
             .attr("class", "link")
             .attr("x", _rectW / 2)
             .attr("y", _rectH / 2)
             .attr("d", function (d) {
                var o = {
                   x: source.x0,
                   y: source.y0
                };
                return _diagonal({
                      source: o,
                      target: o
                });
             });

         // Transition links to their new position.
         link.transition()
             .duration(_duration)
             .attr("d", _diagonal);

         // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
         link.exit().transition()
             .duration(_duration)
             .attr("d", function (d) {
                 var o = {
                     x: source.x,
                     y: source.y
                 };
                 return _diagonal({
                     source: o,
                     target: o
                 });
             })
             .remove();
      }

      // Stash the old positions for transition.
      _nodes.forEach(function (d) {
          d.x0 = d.x;
          d.y0 = d.y;
      });
   },

   // Toggle children on click.
   nodeclick = function(d) {      
      if (!d.children && !d._children && d.hasChild) {
         // If there are no childs --> Try to load child nodes
         _loadFunction(d, function(childs) {
            var response = {id: d.id, 
                            desc: d.desc, 
                            children: childs.result};

            response.children.forEach(function(child){
               if (!_tree.nodes(d)[0]._children){
                   _tree.nodes(d)[0]._children = [];
               }

               child.x  = d.x;
               child.y  = d.y;
               child.x0 = d.x0;
               child.y0 = d.y0;
               _tree.nodes(d)[0]._children.push(child);
            });    

            if (d.children) {
               _callerNode = d;
               _callerMode = 0;     // Collapse
               d._children = d.children;
               d.children = null;
            } else {
               _callerNode = null;
               _callerMode = 1;     // Expand
               d.children = d._children;
               d._children = null;
            }

            update(d);
         });
      } else {
         if (d.children) {
            _callerNode = d;
             _callerMode = 0;     // Collapse
             d._children = d.children;
             d.children = null;
         } else {
            _callerNode = d;
            _callerMode = 1;     // Expand             
             d.children = d._children;
             d._children = null;
         }

         update(d);
      }
   },

   //Redraw for zoom
   redraw = function() {
     _svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + 
                            " scale(" + d3.event.scale.toFixed(1) + ")");
   },

   initTree = function(options) {
      var u_opts = $.extend({id: "",
                             data: {}, 
                             modus: "line", 
                             loadFunc: function() {}
                            },
                            options),
      id = u_opts.id;

      _loadFunction = u_opts.loadFunc;
      _mode = u_opts.modus;
      _root = u_opts.data;

      if(_mode == "line") {
         _fixedDepth = 80;
      } else {
         _fixedDepth = 110;
      }

      $(id).html("");   // Reset
      var width  = $(id).innerWidth()  - _margin.left - _margin.right,
          height = $(id).innerHeight() - _margin.top  - _margin.bottom;

      _tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([_rectW + _rectSpacing, _rectH + _rectSpacing]);

      /* Basic Setup for the diagonal function. _mode = "diagonal" */
      _diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
          .projection(function (d) {
          return [d.x + _rectW / 2, d.y + _rectH / 2];
      });

      /* Basic setup for the line function. _mode = "line" */
      _lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                           .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                           .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                           .interpolate("linear");

      var u_childwidth = parseInt((_root.children.length * _rectW) / 2);

      _svgroot = d3.select(id).append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
                   .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.15,3]).on("zoom", redraw));

      _svg = _svgroot.append("g")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(" + parseInt(u_childwidth + ((width - u_childwidth * 2) / 2) - _margin.left / 2) + "," + 20 + ")");

      var u_stops = [{offset: "0%", color: "#03A9F4", opacity: 1}, {offset: "100%", color: "#0288D1", opacity: 1}];
      defLinearGradient("gradientnochilds", "0%", "0%", "0%" ,"100%", u_stops);
      var u_stops = [{offset: "0%", color: "#8BC34A", opacity: 1}, {offset: "100%", color: "#689F38", opacity: 1}];
      defLinearGradient("gradientchilds", "0%", "0%", "0%" ,"100%", u_stops);

      defBoxShadow("boxShadow");

      //necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
      zm.translate([parseInt(u_childwidth + ((width - u_childwidth * 2) / 2) - _margin.left / 2), 20]);

      _root.x0 = 0;           // the root is already centered
      _root.y0 = height / 2;  // draw & animate from center

      _root.children.forEach(collapse);
      update(_root);

      d3.select(id).style("height", height + _margin.top + _margin.bottom);
   };

   return { initTree: initTree};
})();

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="body"></div>

<button onclick='orgChart.initTree({id: "#body", data: u_data, modus: "line", loadFunc: loadChilds});'>Classic OrgChart</button>
<button onclick='orgChart.initTree({id: "#body", data: u_data, modus: "diagonal", loadFunc: loadChilds});'>Modern OrgChart</button>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var u_data = {};

function loadChilds(actualElement, successFunction) {
   $.getJSON("/Examples/D3.js/OrgChart/getPositions.php?id=" + actualElement.id, 
          function(data) {
             successFunction(data);
          });
}

$.getJSON("/Examples/D3.js/OrgChart/getPositions.php?id=0", 
          function(data) {
             u_data = data;
             orgChart.initTree({id: "#body", data: data, modus: "diagonal", loadFunc: loadChilds});
          });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

working example here: https://blog.zubasoft.at/Examples/D3.js/OrgChart/

Comment: Neat! Does this code respects orientation? So it chart is left to right, it will still show straight lines?

Answer (score 0):

Since [this PR](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/pull/177) you can use [`d3.link()`](https://d3js.org/d3-shape/link#link), which takes a [curve](https://d3js.org/d3-shape/curve) as a parameter.

You may want to use [curveStep](https://d3js.org/d3-shape/curve#curveStep) to produce a graph similar to the image shared in OP:

```
d3.link(d3.curveStep)
```

[image]

Check the tree images shared in the PR (like the one above) to see how the tree will look like for each curve.